# CSS positioning not changing for -webkit-

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome

Probably a very simple question for anyone well versed in CSS, but I'm working on a public facing website, and am trying to configure the layout... works fine for FF and IE, but chrome seems to want to place things in strange positions... here's my css...

```
#HeaderLinks
{    
color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
/*top: -73%;*/
top: -ms- -73%;
top: -moz- -73%;
top: -webkit- -200px; /*Chrome*/

/*width: 940px;*/
width:95%;
z-index:100;
text-align: right;
position:relative;
}
```

problem is that the -webkit- line, for chrome, doesn't seem to do anything... no matter what I change that value to, it doesn't change how it's displayed on the screen... is there a different syntax for using the "top" descriptor in chrome?

Comment: vendor prefixes are placed *before* CSS style properties and not the values, and are only for non-agreed styles pending for CSS3 in which case each vendor has their own implementation. `top` is not such a property. You should also try to avoid specifically coding for each browser if at all possible

Comment: Sounds like somebody needs a reset.css or normalize.css: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prefixes are used for non-standard css3 properties in all sites, 
the TOP property is a standard supported across browsers

besides prefixes take precedence over properties not value

-webkit-property: value; 
-moz-property: value; 
-o-property: value; 
property: value;

Comment: that kinda makes sense... but obviously "top" is being interpreted differently... what is the best way to define one "top" value for IE and a different one for FF and a different one for chrome?

Comment: @Jon it seems you are looking for some browser specific CSS code.. why different top values for every browser?

Comment: @Jon I usually add a class to the body tag using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower()` (C#, may be different if you're using vb) then you can add different styles per browser

Comment: @KheemaPandey like I said, when the page is rendered in the different browsers, the location of elements is different... usually not by much, but enough that if it looks clean on IE, then chrome puts a few elements in slightly different places, enough to make it look sloppy... same with if I clean it up on FF, then it's off on the IE, and the same issue happens between all 3, and I haven't even tested with opera yet :/

Comment: @jon try doing do reset css ( http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/ )
this clean padding, margin, font and other things that every browser included by default to your pages

you need  implement this in the beginning of your css file

Comment: @Pete I'm using VB.NET, but I think I get what you're saying... I can do a response.writeline to set the css file, just having one for IE and one for the others? after googling it, I could only find that distinction... will that find me different results for FF vs Chrome? the 2 are behaving differently, so I'd need to do a diff CSS file for each I think...

Comment: @Pete if you repost that as an answer, I'll accept it.  Doing it from code-behind works and so it's just a matter of using different CSS files (copies with tweaks.) So very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Jon Mark this one as the answer as it answers your initial question, my comment just gives a work around which people can see if they look at this answer